# Black screen on app launch after latest Xcode 7.2 update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

i am making a very complicated app with a lot of classes.
my app worked great and i worked on it for the last month.
the last time i worked on it i added a function and it worked great, i saved the app and ran it a few times since and it worked. the last time i turned my computer on, it prompted me that an update for xcode is available. i updated it, and since then every time i run my app it runs with no errors but on ios simulator it shows a black screen. what can i do? i worked really hard on that app. thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's few issues that could happened, withou detailed description of this issue, you can try following solutions:

- reset simulator

[image]

- check if your initial controller is set up in storyboard(select controller and press attribute inspector, select is initial view controller):

[image]

- if you're setting initial view controller programmatically, check if that controller is not nil in app delegate

another tip - try to use UI debugger, that helps a lot:

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for your help first of all. now, i have my viewcontroller set as main, and i tried this reset in the simulator which didn't help. the UI debugger show me nothing but a black screen too. the app worked fine and i didn't change anything except that i updated Xcode, and then the problem started.. any ideas?

Comment: in your viewController, can you log something or put breakpoint in viewDidLoad method, see if it's actually calling your controller

Comment: hi, i want to thank you! i had to put a breakpoint on my viewDidLoad to see that it doesn't even gets called, and then i just went to the storyBoard and changed the rootviewcontroller to my viewcontroller because somehow it lost it.

Answer (score 0):

Any debug messages in the Xcode output? That usually will give a clue.

One thing I can think of, is that in your

`- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application`

delegate, try setting the window's root view controller to your view controller. Example:

```
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Again, the Xcode debug output will confirm if this is indeed the case though.

Comment: hi, i have another view controller that is set a the main by the storyboard, so this doesn't help me.. thanks